# Is there a way to reset a std::variant from a known alternative?

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

I'm in the process of updating a codebase that is currently using a custom equivalent of `std::variant` to C++17 .

In certain parts of the code, the variant is being reset from a known alternative, so the class provides a method that asserts that `index()` is at a current value, but still directly invokes the proper destructor unconditionally.

This is used in some tight inner loops, and has (measured) non-trivial performance impact. That's because it allows the compiler to eliminate the entire destruction when the alternative in question is a trivially destructible type.

At face value, it seems to me that I can't achieve this with the current `std::variant<>` implementation in the STL, but I'm hoping that I'm wrong.

Is there a way to accomplish this that I'm not seeing, or am I out of luck?

**Edit:** as requested, here's a usage example (using @T.C's example as basis):

```
struct S {
    ~S();
};

using var = MyVariant<S, int, double>;

void change_int_to_double(var& v){
  v.reset_from<1>(0.0);
}
```

`change_int_to_double` compiles to effectively:

```
@change_int_to_double(MyVariant<S, int, double>&)
  mov qword ptr [rdi], 0       // Sets the storage to double(0.0)
  mov dword ptr [rdi + 8], 2   // Sets the index to 2
```

**Edit #2**

Thanks to various insight from @T.C., I've landed on this monstrosity. It "works" even though it does violate the standard by skipping a few destructors. However, every skipped destructor is checked at compile-time to be trivial so...:

see on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/g/2LK2fa

```
// Let's make sure our std::variant implementation does nothing funky internally.
static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<std::variant<char, int>>::value, 
          "change_from_I won't be valid");

template<size_t I, typename arg_t, typename... VAR_ARGS>
void change_from_I(std::variant<VAR_ARGS...>& v, arg_t&& new_val) {
    assert(I == v.index());

    // Optimize away the std::get<> runtime check if possible.
    #if defined(__GNUC__) 
      if(v.index() != I) __builtin_unreachable();
    #else
      if(v.index() != I) std::terminate();
    #endif


    // Smart compilers handle this fine without this check, but MSVC can 
    // use the help.
    using current_t = std::variant_alternative_t<I, std::variant<VAR_ARGS...>>;
    if(!std::is_trivially_destructible<current_t>::value) {
        std::get<I>(v).~current_t();
    }
    new (&v) var(std::forward<arg_t>(new_val));
}
```

Comment: by chance are all the types in the variant trivially destructible?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x It's kinda squirreled away deep within a template hierarchy, so the answer is: sometimes yes, sometimes no. I haven't tested wether the compiler handles the yes case or not, but it doesn't matter as I want it to work when it's mixed.

Comment: "*the variant is being reset from a known alternative*" What does that mean, exactly? Can you provide code using your old type that demonstrates this?

Comment: Something like https://godbolt.org/g/8zypv4?

Comment: @T.C. No, because there's still a runtime check, In my version, the `cmp` and `jne` are not there. (Though I will say that I am impressed the compiler pulled this off, it might be close enough, if not ideal)

Comment: @NicolBolas Updated the question with a specific example.

Comment: GCC gives you what you want if you use `__builtin_unreachable()` instead of `terminate()`. Clang's codegen is terrible with that though.

Comment: @T.C. Oh Wow! That's awesome, I just have to get clang and MSVC to play ball, but this is encouraging enough for me to proceed. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <variant>
struct S {
    ~S();
};
using var = std::variant<S, int, double>;

void change_int_to_double(var& v){
    if(v.index() != 1) __builtin_unreachable();
    v = 0.0;
}
```

GCC [compiles the function down to](https://godbolt.org/g/TKFMj5):

```
change_int_to_double(std::variant<S, int, double>&):
  mov QWORD PTR [rdi], 0x000000000
  mov BYTE PTR [rdi+8], 2
  ret
```

which is optimal. Clang's codegen, OTOH, leaves much to be desired, although it [isn't too bad](https://godbolt.org/g/LgGw5U) if you use `std::terminate()` (the equivalent of an assertion) rather than `__builtin_unreachable()`:

```
change_int_to_double(std::__1::variant<S, int, double>&): # @change_int_to_double(std::__1::variant<S, int, double>&)
  cmp dword ptr [rdi + 8], 1
  jne .LBB0_2
  mov qword ptr [rdi], 0
  mov dword ptr [rdi + 8], 2
  ret
.LBB0_2:
  push rax
  call std::terminate()
```

MSVC...let's not talk about MSVC.

Comment: For reference,  yeah, MSVC (2017) actually maintains a call to `std::_Variant_base<S,int,double>::_Reset` even with the most aggressive optimization options when using the `std::terminate` approach. Which is... not great...

Comment: I upvoted the answer but won't accept it just yet. I would much rather have a solution that performs this in code (like I used to have), rather than hoping the compiler optimizes it for me. I do understand that may not be possible right now though...

Comment: @Frank Hmm, there's always the check-trivial-destructible-and-placement-new-over-the-thing approach if you want to go that way...

Comment: I would need a way to set the just the index in order to be able to do that.

Comment: @Frank No, you placement new a whole new `variant`.

Comment: improving on that a bit: https://godbolt.org/g/VA4U9d. This is walking a verrrrrrry thin line, and is technically invalid, but "safe enough" with the static_assert in place (I think).

Comment: 1. If you want to play a little more by the books, just use plain assignment if the current alternative isn't trivially destructible. Might be a little more expensive, but you are calling a dtor anyway.  2. In general, skipping dtors is fine as long as you don't depend on their side effects. 3. The dtor of `std::variant` [must be trivial](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/variant.dtor#2) if every alternative is trivially destructible.