# Is there any reason not to wrap assert() in a macro that resolves to __builtin_unreachable() in gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, assert

Context:  In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46149999/4442671), I learned that gcc's `__builtin_unreachable()` can have some surprisingly impactful performance implications, as it seems that the following:

```
if(condition) __builtin_unreachable();
```

is being entirely stripped, and used as an optimization hint as long as `condition` can be guaranteed to not have any side effect.

So my immediate reaction to this is that I should create the following macro, and use it absolutely everywhere I would normally use `assert()`, since side-effect inducing code inside an `assert()` would be a major bug in the first place:

```
// TODO: add handling of other compilers as appropriate.
#if defined(__GNUC__) && defined(NDEBUG)
  #define my_assert(condition) \
    if(!(condition)) __builtin_unreachable()
#else 
  #define my_assert(condition) assert(condition)
#endif
```

From a standards perspective, this would create a split in functionality between normal and `NDEBUG` builds, which you could make an argument excludes this macro from being the standard behavior of `assert()`. However, since my code would be functionally dead in the water in the case of assertion failures regardless, it's fully equivalent from a behavioral standpoint.

So my question is: Can anyone think of a reason not to do this (appart from asserts that involve a lot of indirections)?

Before you ask, yes, I've checked that gcc's behavior is to void cast the assertion away in `NDEBUG` builds.

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/40447259/817643

Comment: No reason not to do this, as far as I can tell. You assume something for optimization in release builds, and replace it by an assertion in debug builds to catch programming errors.

Comment: "use it absolutely everywhere" approach won't really work because debug assertions often include variables and calls that are only available in debug mode. The better idea would be define a dedicated macro with a more suitable name such as `my_assume` and utilize it only in appropriate places.

Comment: In general, one can put things in asserts which have side effects, so I would not do this. For example, there can be an expensive function which checks some invariant: `assert(isStructureValid());`. I definitely don't want to see that function called in release builds. So, as others suggested, create a new `assume` (or some other name) macro for this functionality. Or, with come compiler magic, only apply the check in release builds if the `condition` can be evaluated compile-time.

Comment: @geza limiting this to compile-time conditions would defeat the entire purpose (see the linked question for an example).

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "that a variable satisfies a compile-time constraint", like `assert(variable<=5);`. The intent of this comment was that the compiler optimize away the whole expression, and use the additional knowledge to optimize better.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a reason to not use it.
Some people use the following defensive code practice that combines assert and exception ( `assert(x>0); if (!(x<0)) throw std::logic_error("..")` ) - see this answer:

[Test Cases AND assertion statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168/test-cases-and-assertion-statements#56174)

Your macro silently breaks the exception-part for release builds.

Comment: I really don't like this practice, as it conflates programming errors and runtime errors. That assert has no business being there in my opinion. My codebase wouldn't suffer from this, but a this is a good thing to keep in mind.

Comment: I don't see the value in that tbh. It seems to defeat the purpose of `assert()` as having zero runtime impact on release code. May as well just use the exception if that's what you want.

Comment: This is not defensive but redundant code. If you need to put checks in release builds, then either create a special, compiled-even-in-release-mode release_assert, or use exception throwing only. Assert+throw is bad practice.

Comment: @Galik It's not so much as whether than idiom is valuable or not, but the fact that usage of my macro would lead to UB in seemingly well-defined programs, which is a perfectly valid point, and reinforces the need for the macro to be appropriately named.

Comment: @Frank: I disagree. If a program doesn't satisfies an assert, then it is not a well-defined program. Even if that assert is not there, because it is compiled away. But I agree with you that a different named macro should be used for this purpose.

Comment: When I find myself writing that, I avoid repeating myself so I write `if (!(x < 0)) { assert(false); throw std::logic_error(".."); }`.  I guess OP's proposal would break on that too. Seems like the only safe thing is a different macro that clearly refers to the unreachability.